# Add class to input field if the field has a value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Thanks in advance!

Please could someone help me I need to add a class ".filled" to the input field below if the value field isn't null?

`<input name="total_price" class="form-control" id="ProposalPriceTotal" type="text" value="{{ $proposal->total_price }}">`

Full Code:
https://codepen.io/FluxedDigital/pen/vvJzgX

Thanks!

Comment: what framework do you use?

Comment: Im using Laravel

Comment: Coul you not do a ternary statement in php to add the class if the total_price is not empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do that with PHP ternary operator. You can Google it later for explanation. It just a simple code:

```
<input name="total_price" class="form-control {{ $proposal->total_price 
== null ? '' : 'filled' }}" id="ProposalPriceTotal" type="text" value=" 
{{ $proposal->total_price }}">
```

Surely, the comparison value is depend on your type of data. But I think that using `null` should be fine.

Comment: Ive just tried that but it didn't work.

I don't need to target 1 specific input field, I need to target all input fields.

Sorry if that wasn't clear

Comment: what you got in your console? Is there any error or something?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/9qam9vE

if you look at the top field. the placeholder is behind the value of the field. I need to add the '.filled' class so it moves the placeholder above the value.

Comment: If you check with inspect element, it should real time added the class you want. Just try to type something then click on empty space, you'll see some changes. But I can't assure it will work at your machine since you didn't write your complete code

Comment: Hi Adrian, I have checked with inspector and its not adding the class.

Ill add the code to the question above for you

Comment: okay. So did you mean it will add class dynamically? I meant, if someone deleted the input field, then the class will be gone and vice versa (add class when someone input something)? Or it depends on actual data in database? In this case `$proposal->total_price`

Comment: It depends on the data from the database.
Here is how it should look:

When the value is empty:
<input name="total_price" class="form-control" id="ProposalPriceTotal" type="text" value="">

When there is a value (has 'filled' class):
<input name="total_price" class="form-control filled" id="ProposalPriceTotal" type="text" value="Has Value">

Comment: Oh I see. You mentioned about JS snippets so I think it's based on user input which is real time. Wait and I will update my answer.